# Can the return statement execute more than once in Java as opposed to Python?

Tags: java, python, methods, return

Considering that Python could execute a return statement in a function at most one time, can Java execute the statement more than once?

Comment: Only if you call the function more than once.

Comment: yes. if you have a finally block. but only one value will actually return.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No. A method can _have_ more than one return statement, but can _execute_ only one of them.

Comment: @BackSlash It can execute two, though only the second will be visible. `try { return 1; } finally { return 2; }` -- both of those return statements will be executed.

Comment: @yshavit, Technically yes. But you will always get value 2, because return 2 will be first return statement executed successfully. Anyways your IDE should be able to throw a warning for write such non-sense.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand When it comes to JLS, my attitude is summed up by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo :)

Comment: @yshavit, well i never said, you are wrong. Just it's non-sense to write something like that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java function can only execute one return statement per iteration.

Doesn't matter how many return statements you write in a function, first one found in traversed path of function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Java methods may only return one value on a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, a new frame is added to the call-stack which contains that function's variables, parameters, etc.

When you return from a function in Java (and any other languages I know of), the stack frame for that function is removed from the call-stack.  The function no longer exists (in that particular call instance as pointed out by John Walgreen).

So, calling return more than once would not many any sense (and it isn't possible).  You can have multiple return statements, but only one will ever be invoked on any given function call depending on the path taken through the function.